# Sphinx catch error while reading sources

Tags: bash, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am using sphinx for documentation. and have used the make html and make latexpdf through a bash script.
when running the bash script, and when make html is run, it shows ERROR in teh rst file after the Reading sources.

```
make clean
+ make clean
rm -rf _build/*
make html
+ make html
sphinx-build -b html -d _build/doctrees   . _build/html
Running Sphinx v1.3b3
making output directory...
loading pickled environment... not yet created
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [html]: targets for 2 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 2 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] index
/home/sphinx/Inder.rst:12:WARNING: Bullet list ends without a blank line; unexpected unindent.
/home/sphinx/Inder.rst:12: ERROR: Document may not end with a transition.
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [100%] index
```

How can i catch this error in the bash script or send it to another variable.
i have tried grep ERROR with the make html, but it gives blank.

Comment: `grep it out` as in just hide from showing in `stdout`?

Comment: i meant using something like this - RESULT= make html | grep ERROR.
 so that i could store it in a variable and check the variable if it contains an error. else continue.

Comment: @InderjeetSingh: Can you provide feedback on the solutions below? to let us know if it worked? And if it did, can you mark the working answer _accepted_ by clicking on the tick mark on the left of the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sphinx-build` will probably print output on both stdout and stderr so you likely want to capture both streams.

You can do this like:

```
out=$(make html 2>&1)
if grep -q 'ERROR: ' <<< "$out"; then
    # do some error handling
fi
```